# Querying custom types in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Imagine I have three classes like these :

```
public class Employee {
  public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
  public string Fname {get;set;}
  public File Picture {get;set;}
}

public class Employer {
  public int EmployerId {get;set;}
  public string Fname {get;set;}
  public string WorkingPlace{get;set;}
  public File Pictrue {get;set;}
}

public class File {
  public int FileId {get;set;}
  public byte[] Content {get;set;}
  public int Size {get;set;}
}
```

First, Is above code right way to save files and images of different entities? and then this is my context class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{     
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employer> Employers { get; set; }
}
```

When I have query like this :

```
MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext
var q = from emp in context.Employees
        where emp.EmployeeId == 4
        select emp;
Console.WriteLine(q.First().Picture.FileId)
```

I get 0 as `FileId` while I see it's not 0 when I look in database.
Somehow `q.First().Picture` is not set correctly

Comment: have you configured your modelBuilder? code first convention should map FileId on EmployeeId because of one-to-one relation. Anyways, Use Include(x=>x.Picture) before calling first to populate the navigation property before the value is materialized.

Comment: *Imagine*... What do your real classes look like, esp. the constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options available: `eager loading` or `lazy loading`.  You can get more detail about them from this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Lazy loading is generally considered best practice, because you should only load what you need into memory by default; and then adjust accordingly on a per query basis.

For Lazy Loading, all you have to do is add `virtual` to the property in question:

```
public class Employee {
  public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
  public string Fname {get;set;}
  public virtual File Picture {get;set;}
}
```

This should make your query work as expected; however, it will probably result in 2 database calls, which would be inefficient.  To address that, you can eager load the data as part of the query using `.Include<>`

```
MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext
var q = context.Employees.Include(e => e.Picture).Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 4);
var q2 = context.Employees.Include("Picture").Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 4); //Alternative syntax
Console.WriteLine(q.First().Picture.FileId)
```

Comment: context.Employees doesn't have any Include function taking a lambda expression

Comment: @n3verLieMe updated my answer with the alternative syntax `.Include("Picture")`  Not sure why that happens; probably a missing using.

Comment: The term you're looking for is `Navigation Property`.